# Should you include press interviews and articles about your work in your CV?

Tags: cv

Is it appropriate to include interviews (published online or in print magazines) in an academic CV?

What about articles/news published about your works? I mean brief (one paragraph) news that professional magazines publish about significant research articles.

If yes, how do you do this to avoid exaggeration?

Comment: I think it is ok to include a line about the interview if it highlights the value of your work. May be add a line in "Honors and Achievements" section.

Comment: I wouldn't put this under "Honors and Achievements"... rather under "Appearances in Popular Media", or "Popularization", or "Outreach" or some such.

Answer (score 8):

It depends, but yes, I would include media exposure in a long form CV. This could be advantageous for grant applications, because it might be an evidence that you can generate a higher impact.

For each media exposure, just put one line as a citation format. If you have more than 10 such items, select only the higher impact ones, and merge ones with similar content.

Alternatively, you can put it is a footnote to your relevant publication.

Comment: For the footnote to your relevant publication, I think this might be more appropriate for something like a press release about a specific work than an interview, but even there, I think a different section might be better.

Answer (score 2):

Officially no need to include newspaper or magazine article containing an interview about the results of your achievement in science and technology in an academic CV, but it can be a plus factor when you're applying for a grant or scholarship where other applicants quite competitive. It will gives the reviewer impression of your commitment to areas of interest and the society impact of your researches.

Comment: Remember that with CV, you don't aim at "officially", rather you aim at "put whatever there that's true and makes me get the money".