# How would you cite in your CV a "Meet Our Editorial Board Member"?

Tags: citations, cv, editors

How would you cite in your CV a "Meet Our Editorial Board Member"?

For instance:

http://benthamscience.com/journals/current-bioinformatics/volume/10/issue/3/page/241/

It has DOI, therefore it must be citable, but it is of course not a research publication. So if one cites it on her CV, in which part would it go?

Comment: Why would you put that on a CV in the first place? If you are the editorial-board member to be met, you should have achievements that drastically outshine having been meetable (e.g., *being* an editorial board member). If not, just authoring such an article does not seem much of an academic achievement at all.

Comment: A DOI is a digital object identifier. It just..identifies..objects. It is not a DOI that makes things citable.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft of course being an editorial member is more impressive than being meetable, but OP may want to provide the DOI reference as a way to provide supporting evidence for the claim of being an editorial member (and subtly impress readers of his CV with a clickable link to his editorial board member bio blurb). That sounds reasonable, and in that case that would go under "Professional Service", e.g., as a bullet entry: "Editorial board member, Current Bioinformatics (2013-present). [hyperlinked DOI reference]". OTOH if (s)he authored the blurb, I agree that's not much of an achievement.

Comment: I also question the worth of putting it on a CV.  That said, if you are the one met, maybe in this sort of section: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/44809/19607 If you were the author, maybe in a section titled "Additional writings" or "Non-research publications."  Think about what else it could fit with on your CV.

Comment: _as a way to provide supporting evidence for the claim of being an editorial member_ — Surely anyone who wants evidence will just look at the journal's web page.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, which is a minor byproduct of professional service, would be most appropriately not be listed explicitly at all.  Instead, it would be covered by listing the editorial position in the professional service section of the CV.

In this particular case, however, I would recommend not listing it at all and investing service elsewhere in something that is not a [spamming scam journal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentham_Science_Publishers#Controversies_and_criticism).

Comment: For what it's worth, the *open-access imprint* of that publisher is on Beall's list; the journal the OP edits doesn't appear to come from that division. Beall has not said anything about the quality of the non-open-access part (which [appears to have been reputable at some point](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Bentham_Science_Publishers), and perhaps some of its journals still are) as he only evaluates open-access journals. This journal has a genuine JCR impact factor, which [some believe](http://libguides.usask.ca/c.php?g=16494&p=1172405) means it isn't a total scam.

Comment: @ff524 Yes, Beall specifically rules the hybrid Bentham Science imprint out of scope of his evaluation, since it offers subscriptions, but that says nothing about its quality.  I find it reasonable, however, that their massive spam and scam OA operation should strongly affect judgement of their other titles as well.